# Redirecting a non-existent file in cgi-bin

Tags: redhat, redirect, cgi, errordocument

We are using RHLE 5.6. I am fairly new with linux and apache. We currently have a website using an archaic exe file in the `cgi-bin` directory for a shopping cart (on Windows). We are migrating this website to the RHLE 5.6 server. The challenge I am running against is redirection for the files pointed at the `commerce.exe` file.

I have tried setting up a `.htaccess` `ErrorDocument` directive in our website folder, but the logs say that apache is not looking in the directory folder for the cgi-bin (`/home/site/`), but rather in `/var/www`. I have tried adding the `.htaccess` directives there and in the `/var/www/cgi-bin` folder, and it still presents me with the 404 error. I am open to creative suggestions - I just need `commerce.exe` to be parsed or redirected to a file that can be parsed.

Thank you!

JMax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but the logs say that apache is not looking in the directory folder
>   for the cgi-bin (`/home/site/`), but rather in `/var/www`

Create a `ScriptAlias` for it, something like this:

```
ScriptAlias /shopping "/home/site"

<Directory /home/site>
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

> I just need `commerce.exe` to be parsed

If `mod_cgi` can 'understand' it, just add an `AddHandler`:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .exe
```

A request for `http://domain.com/shopping/commerce.exe` would cause the server to run the `/home/site/commerce.exe`.

> or redirected to a file that can be parsed.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^commerce\.exe$ anotherfile.cgi [L]
```